# ndk-build not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-build

I know that this is a duplicate question and had been asked hundreds of time. But this error occurs even after adding NDK folder path to System variable path. Please if someone have any idea about this then let me know.

Comment: @Natali - the issue has indeed been covered here many times, but the answers at your link are terrible - at best, horribly outdated and incomplete.  As it stands this question isn't really answerable - we aren't even told on what sort of system this is being attempted and in what context it is failing.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take some time to expand your question. It's not really answerable as it is now: what is your OS? How do you run **ndk-build**? And finally, why do you want to run it now, that Android Studio provides easy automated solution now (for simple cases)?

Comment: Sorry to everyone, I asked the question wrong way. And thank you for the reply, i was including wrong path of ndk. From next time I will ask precise questions.